# How to select and delete, move multiple items in Sitecore 6 content editor?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

How to select and delete, move multiple items in tree in Sitecore 6 content editor?

Answer (score 13):

Now you can easily do this with [Sitecore Rocks](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/44a26c88-83a7-46f6-903c-5c59bcd3d35b)! Download it right from your VS 2010 and give it a try. In order to operate the multiple items you should just select those with Ctrl key down and then use context menu - all well-known operations :)

Good luck!

Comment: I've voted this up as a developer, but the idea of our authors working in VS.... *shudder*

Comment: Never thought of using Rocks, but as James said, it most certainly works from the developer's perspective...

Answer (score 5):

I haven't found a way to do it, other than selecting an entire folder/parent.  I think it's just a limitation of the UI.  Would love to be wrong.